# Efficient method for randomly selecting all elements of a std::vector exactly once WITHOUT reshuffling

Tags: c++, random, vector, std

I am looking for an efficient method for selecting access to each element of a `std::vector<T>` in a random order, without reshuffling or copying them i.e no use of `std::random_shuffle` and ensure that each element is selected only once.

I don't want to copy or reshuffle as a) each instance of `T` is likely to be a very large object and b) for other operations I will be doing on the elements of the vector, it is easier for them to remain in the same order.

Furthermore, I don't really want to go down the street of continuously picking and rejecting duplicates. It is likely I will have lots of these large objects stored in the vector and efficiency is key as I will be looking to call this random selection method many times a second.

Comment: Can you implement a swap method for your type?  If the standard library implementation uses argument-dependent lookup for swap (it should), then you will get `O(1)` swapping of elements in the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not tell us whether you want to iterate over the whole array randomly, or if you only need some elements at random.

I assume the first case. You'll need extra storage for bookkeeping, and you'll need linear time for the shuffling anyway. So create a permutation, and keep its memory alive so that you can reshuffle it as you wish. With C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>

struct permutation
{
    permutation(size_t n) 
        : perm(n), g(std::random_device())
    {
        std::iota(perm.begin(), perm.end(), size_t(0));
    }

    void shuffle() { std::shuffle(perm.begin(), perm.end(), g); }

    size_t operator[](size_t n) const { return perm[n]; }

private:
    std::vector<size_t> perm;
    std::mt19937 g;
};
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<huge_t> v;
...

permutation sigma(v.size());
sigma.shuffle();

const huge_t& x = v[sigma[0]];

...
sigma.shuffle(); // No extra allocation
const huge_t& y = v[sigma[0]];
```

You can adapt the code to use C++03 `std::random_shuffle`, but please note that there are very few guarantees on the random number generator.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using VS2008, which I believe doesn't support c++11

Comment: Note that `std::random_shuffle()` has an overload which accepts a random number generator.  You can pass in a higher quality generator if you wish to.

Comment: Just to clarify, as not familiar with c++11, what needs adapting for use with C++03? or have you already changed the code after your update?

Comment: @AndréCaron: true, but you will agree that it is quite difficult to do it properly, and I wouldn't recommand doing it if it is available via a library.

Comment: There are several implementations of the Mersenne twister available online, as well as `/dev/random` et.al. Wrapping those facilities into a function object is trivial.

Comment: @oracle3001: `std::iota`, and the random number generation are C++11. Also `std::shuffle` is new to C++11. @AndreCaron: drawing a number between 0 and n is tricky to do properly. Also, you have to select a seed somehow. Someone who doesn't know this would do `rand() % n` which is awfully wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Create a vector the same size as the existing one that uses pointers to the elements in the vector.  Randomly shuffle the pointer vector instead and read from there - it's low cost.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest (and one of the more efficient ones) solution would be to either create a `std::vector<size_t>` holding indices into your `vector<T>`, or a `std::vector<T*>` holding the pointers into your `vector`. Then you can shuffle that one using `std::random_shuffle`, iterate over it and pick the corresponding elements from your original vector. That way you don't change the order of your original vector and shuffleing pointers or `size_t` is pretty cheap

Comment: The std::vector<int> method is the way I currently have implemented it, but just wanted to check there wasn't a better way of doing this. Have come back to c++ coding after a couple of year break.

Comment: +1 Basically equivalent to w00te's approach, but the relation to the original vector is clearer, the original vector can be modified in between, and it may be 50% more memory efficent on LP64 systems if you decide that you're lazy and use `int` over `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks guys....The std::vector<int> method is the way I currently have implemented it, but just wanted to check there wasn't a better way of doing this. Have come back to c++ coding after a couple of year break. 

Following on from this....Lets say std::vector<Object> ObjVector and std::vector<int> index

is it possible to use for_each (index.begin(), index.end(), someMethod) to achieve the following...someMethod in someway ends up in a call to method Obj.method i.e for_each results in calls to method in each instance of Object in ObjVector in a random order?

Comment: use std::vector<T*> and std::vector<T*>::iterator

Comment: Which is better? Storing a std::vector<T>::const_iterator or std::vector<T*> as the indexing method? And do I really need to store std::vector<T*> and std::vector<T*>::iterator?

Comment: @oracle3001: For optimized implementations (note: not necessaryly in debug build) `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` is likely to be `const T*`, so it won't make a difference (except of course that `T*` will let you modify the element, so `std::vector<T>::iterator` would a be the corresponding type). I don't understand your question about storing std::vector<T*>::iterator though